# Capistrano: multiserver deploy output is messed up

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

Here is an example output of 3 server deploy:

```
00:06 git:clone
  The repository mirror is at /home/production/site/repo
  The repository mirror is at /home/production/site/repo
  The repository mirror is at /home/production/site/repo
```

All lines from output are messed up and we don't know on what servers they are executed.

How can I format it to something like:

```
00:06 git:clone
  production@server1: The repository mirror is at /home/production/site/repo
  production@server2: The repository mirror is at /home/production/site/repo
  production@server3: The repository mirror is at /home/production/site/repo
```

Answer (score 3):

The default output of Capistrano is formatted according to the [Airbrussh](https://github.com/mattbrictson/airbrussh) gem, which is aimed at making the output concise.

If you prefer more verbose output, try using the `pretty` formatter by adding the following line to your `deploy.rb`:

```
set :format, :pretty
```

That formatter will prefix each line of output with an ID that is unique to each server.

Answer (score 1):

Search for lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake file in your capistrano gem folder. It have a method like this

```
  desc 'Clone the repo to the cache'
  task clone: :'git:wrapper' do
    on release_roles :all do
      if strategy.test
        info t(:mirror_exists, at: repo_path)
      else
        within deploy_path do
          with fetch(:git_environmental_variables) do
            strategy.clone
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Modify

```
info t(:mirror_exists, at: repo_path)
```

as you desired.
I don't know where is the server name variable. But you are now in the right way.

Comment: What should I do if I want to add server to all capistrano tasks?